# Execute JavaScript function using Python requests_html

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am trying to execute a JavaScript function (run with a button click) within a session using Python's `requests_html`

I understand the regular `requests` library does not have JavaScript support so I am trying to use `requests_html` instead.

Here's what I have (using `requests`):

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.post(url)
print(r.text)
r2 = s.post(url2)
print(r2.text)
```

`url` is the link to the page containing the button and `url2` is the POST request link the button's JavaScript function executes. (I found  `url2` through the network tab while in my browser inspector and clicking the button as a test)

However, this does not work and I get this from `r2.text`:

```
<h2>Error(500): An error occurred.</h2>
                <p>We are sorry but an unexpected error has occurred on our side while handling your request. In the meantime, please retry your request or try the following:</p>
```

To my understanding, an error 500 means that the issue is server-side, not client-side. However, clicking the button manually on the webpage works fine.

This brings me to attempting to directly execute the JavaScript function instead. I couldn't find anything on the `requests_html` documentation. I've also looked at Selenium, but that doesn't seem to be up to date.

It is also worth mentioning that the button inspector looks like this: `<button onclick="registerInterest(72833,959320000, '')" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="far fa-clipboard"></i> Register Interest</button>`

So essentially, I would like to execute `registerInterest(72833,959320000, '')` after my first POST request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
I will gladly provide any additional needed information.

Comment: Just share the browsed url not post req url

Comment: @F.Hoque here’s the link: https://helptobuyagent3.org.uk/find-a-home/property-details?id=71669&bedrooms=3&IDType=2

Comment: What's  the desired output do you expect? would you provide an example? your desired output's example will help to solve the  problem

Comment: @F.Hoque I don’t want an output, I want to to send a request to the webpage; r2.text should return a successful confirmation instead of an error

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Selenium for manipulating html elements. You can use code like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
#set chromodriver.exe path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
#implicit wait
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
#maximize browser
driver.maximize_window()
#launch URL
driver.get("https://www.tutorialspoint.com/index.htm")
#identify element
l =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Check it Now']")
#perform click
l.click()
print("Page title is: ")
print(driver.title)
#close browser
driver.quit()
```

Just check docs on methods of Selenium and find a method which fits you the best.

Comment: This does not affirmatively address the OP's cited concerns around `500 Server Error` responses being returned in their specific scenario.